# How should I use machine learning classifiers on a a training set that contains text?

Tags: java, machine-learning, nlp, classification

I am working on finding errors and predicting their possible causes by going through log files.
In order to apply a classifier on it I need the text to be a numeral. I can identify keywords by NER and need it to be used as a training set. Can anyone suggest me some ways to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swapnil, people usually "make the text numeral" by representing it as a vector: you enumerate all the words you have seen in the training set, and then for every word in document you set the n-th element of a big vector. This approach is usually called [Vector Space Model](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/vector-space-classification-1.html)
In your case some words and combinations of words may be "special" (like "ERROR" and "WARNING" in the beginning of log messages), you can group them in the beginning of your vector and treat them slightly differently from the words from explanation text - in terms of values you assign to them, for example.
(Obviously, if you can detect entire entities using Named Entity Recognition, you treat each as one element in your vector.)